# QgsRasterLayer WMS XYZ tiles pops warnings on status 204

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, xyz-tiles

I created a QGIS plugin.

I added a xyz_tiles layer with the following code.

```
        layer = QgsRasterLayer(self.url, layer_name, "wms")
        
        if layer.isValid():
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
        else:
            print("Layer failed to load!")
```

QGIS files with warnings.

How to close these warnings?

[image]